# AFNetworking Having trouble making a request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am new to AFNetworking and I am having a nightmare of a time with it.

So far I have created this method:

```
-(void)UserLogin:(NSString *)user andPassWordExists:(NSString *)password completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *resultsObject, NSError *error))completionHandler
{


   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kIP];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                         initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[@"domain" stringByAppendingString:user]
                                                        password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession]];

    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(responseObject, nil);
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(nil, error);
        }

    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

I am just super confused on what the next step would be. I have this other method inside another file and I would like to call the UserLogin method and pass in a username and password, would I want to do this like this:

```
- (void)Login
{
    NSString *rawString = [self.idTextField text];
    NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    [self.idTextField setText:[rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace]];


    [userName User:self.idTextField.text andPassWordExists:self.passwordTextField.text:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (responseObject) {
            //We have a user.
        }
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of your second snippit is correct but it's unclear what the "userName" object is. That should be an instance of the class where the first snippit's method can be located, and the name of the method you created was "UserLogin" (you put "User").

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: If your first snippit is contained in a file called Networking.m. you could call the method you wrote with: `Networking *networking = [[Networking alloc] init]` and: `[networking UserLogin:self.idTextField.text andPassWordExists:self.passwordTextField.text completionHandler:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) { ... }];` This is more of an OOP question than anything else - if you haven't worked a lot with Objective C you should focus on the language first before trying to do anything network related.